# How to install kernel on debian with no internet connection

Tags: debian, kernel, software-installation

I'm trying to install a newer kernel version on my Debian (squeeze) machine as I need it to get my wireless card working. I have Debian on one partition of my hard drive, Fedora on the other. I'm looking for SIMPLE instructions on how to do this which I cannot find anywhere on the net. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm even wondering if it is possible to copy the kernel across from one partition to the next?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a machine that is connected to the internet, and that `apt` is properly configured on your squeeze machine, you can do e.g.

```
apt-get install --print-uris linux-image-2.6.32
```

which will give you a list of urls for packages to install. Then you can  use another machine to download them. On my machine, for example, this list starts with

> 'http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/pool/main/l/linux-2.6/linux-image-2.6.32-5-486_2.6.32-39_i386.deb'
> linux-image-2.6.32-5-486_2.6.32-39_i386.deb 27475516
> MD5Sum:be5608eefba4b7180d91b7888abde8da

Then you can download the packages on another machine by doing (for example)

```
wget -c http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/pool/main/l/linux-2.6/linux-image-2.6.32-5-486_2.6.32-39_i386.deb
```

Then copy them to your Debian machine. Then do

```
dpkg -i linux-image-2.6.32-5-486_2.6.32-39_i386.deb pkg2.deb pkg3.deb...
```

You need to give all the package files as arguments.

If you see errors, try running this command again. Sometimes `dpkg`, when called with a list of packages which are dependent on each other, has trouble with dependency resolution. If it still doesn't work, try

```
apt-get -f install
```

which will try to resolve your dependencies.

An alternative is gdebi

```
apt-cache show gdebi
```

> Description: Simple tool to install deb files - GNOME GUI  gdebi lets
> you install local deb packages resolving and installing  its
> dependencies. apt does the same, but only for remote (http, ftp)
> located packages.

Current versions of `apt` support the installation of deb files, and handle dependency resolution for them. So one can do, instead

```
apt-get install ./linux-image-2.6.32-5-486_2.6.32-39_i386.deb ./pkg2.deb ./pkg3.deb...
```

One needs to specify the location of the deb files, here, hence the `./`, which of course means current directory here.

Comment: on my debian machine that is not connected to the internet the --print-uris command finds nothing. how will it know what packages it needs if its not connected to the internet?

Comment: @james: It uses the apt cache if present, but this does assume that it has at some point been connected to the internet, and that you ran `apt-get update`, so it has the cache. If not, you'll have to manually go through the list of packages it wants. How did you do the installation?

Comment: @james: Perhaps you could give more details about your setup, as in, which systems do you have connected to the internet, why you can't connect the Debian installation to the internet temporarily (which would be the simplest thing), and the history of the Debian installation, like how you installed it and whether it has ever been on the network.

Comment: i have installed debian cd 1 on one partition of my hard drive. i have a rtl8191se wireless card which will not work as of yet on debian, on my other partition i have fedora. no problems wireless is working fine.. recently i updated my debian kernel its now 2.6.39 and downloaded the drivers for the rtl8191se card. when i try to compile make keeps bringing up errors :/

Comment: @james: Ok. The drivers for the card are not included in the kernel I take it? I suggest you post the errors.

Comment: ok my kernel version was 2.6.34 my realtek 8191se firmware driver said it needs at least 2.6.35. so now thanks to below post i have 2.6.39-bpo.2-686-pae. but now when i try run make in the driver directory it says "make entering directory lib/module/2.6.39-bpo.2-686-pae//build, no rule to make target 'modules', stop." is there a problem with my make? if it helps i been installing i386 packages because on the debian site for squeeze there's no i686 packages. my kernel is in i686 however

Comment: @james: this is not a compile error. Sounds like you are have some kind of configuration error, or you are trying to compile in the wrong place, as it is not finding the makefile. Check that your module is not (a) already included in the kernel and (b) there are no Debian sources available for it. If that is the case, you could just compile a deb. As gilles suggests, repost, and include as much information as you can about how you are trying to compile the module. What is the name of the module?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a more recent version of the kernel than what's in Debian squeeze. The easiest thing to try is the kernel from the **[backports](http://backports.debian.org/)**. The kernel is in a package called `linux-image-$VERSION-$FLAVOR`. Pick the flavor from what you already have (e.g. `686` or `686-bigmem` or `amd64` or … and get the most recent version you can find. The [sqeeze backports](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=linux-image&searchon=names&section=all&suite=squeeze-backports) currently have version 2.6.39.

If that's recent enough for you, download the `.deb` file from the website and copy it to your machine however you like (e.g. on a USB stick). Also grab every package that's listed as a dependency; you'll need the package containing the actual kernel file (not just the `linux-image-2.6-…` metapackage) and updated [`initramfs-tools`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/initramfs-tools), and possibly more recent [`firmware-linux-free`](http://packages.debian.org/firmware-linux-free) and other [firmware](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=firmware) as well. Install the packages by typing the command `dpkg -iGE /path/to/*.deb` as root in a terminal. This will automatically create an entry for the new kernel in the boot menu. Reboot and see if it works.

If you need to recompile third-party modules in addition to what's distributed ith the kernel, grab the `linux-headers-…` package alongside the `-image-` package.

If you find you need an even more recent kernel (3.0 or 3.1), it doesn't look like there's any readily available package for Debian squeeze at the moment. Try a [3.x kernel](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&arch=i386&searchon=names&keywords=linux-image-3) from testing or unstable (or even a 3.2rc in experimental). Note that this may require more effort; you may need more recent module and initramfs tools.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i got my kernel updated using your advice. only problem now is i still cant get my wireless card working :/.. if i type in ifconfig wlan0 up it says theres no such device. im having trouble makeing the drivers. if i go into the driver directory and type make it brings up an error

Comment: @james It's impossible to help you more without knowing what your wireless card is and what the errors are. I suggest that you ask a new question “How to make XXX wireless card work on Debian squeeze” (where XXX is the model of your wireless card), and mention what you tried (what kernel and driver versions you used, where you got them from, what commands you ran…) and copy-paste the error messages.

Comment: ok sure.. i'll repost. thanks for all the help. i at least go a new kernel package working :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have following scenario, this may be helpful

1. Tried to install Debian Wheezy which have kernel without some WiFi driver which is available only in higher kernel (Not in 3.2 but available in 3.13 version of kernel). You may have found it out by running Debian jessie installation DVD.
2. You do not want jessie which is unstable
3. Now if you install Debian wheezy, you do not have working WiFi/wired connection. So you can not update to newer kernel.

=========Then do as follows (Thanks for above comments)=========

1. In a computer with Internet add jessie in /etc/apt/source.list

   Example: `deb http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/debian/ jessie main`
2. `apt-get update`
3. To find if kernel 3.13 is available `apt-cache search linux-image`
4. `wget -c 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/debian/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.115_all.deb'`
5. `wget -c http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.13-1-amd64_3.13.10-1_i386.deb'`
6. `apt-get download linux-headers-3.13-1-amd64`
7. copy files downloaded to computer with no Internet
8. dpkg -i
9. reboot and select amd64 kernel

Above instructions were helpful to me to install debian wheezy with kernel 3.13 on laptop ACER Aspire V5-123