# Help installing USB wifi drivers in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian

The Leoxsys Nano adapter that I bought recently does not work in my Debian wheezy, but works flawlessly in my Ubuntu. I tried installing using the `install.sh` script that came with the drivers, but still no luck.

This is the output of `install.sh` (the timestamp errors are repeated for various different files. I have removed some of them because the posts was too long, you can see the entire output [here](http://pastebin.com/qgbCKz7E):

```
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_xmit.c
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_xmit.c: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:39 is 280134634.419668702 s in the future
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_halinit.c
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_halinit.c: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:39 is 280134634.417253308 s in the future
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_ops_linux.c: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:39 is 280134634.416732716 s in the future
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/ifcfg-wlan0
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e/usb: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:39 is 280134634.41663481 s in the future
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal/rtl8188e: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:37 is 280134632.416591435 s in the future
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/hal: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:34 is 280134629.416553349 s in the future
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/ifcfg-wlan0: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:37 is 280134632.416436593 s in the future
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/autoconf.h
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/autoconf.h: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:39 is 280134634.416238385 s in the future
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/basic_types.h
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/basic_types.h: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:38 is 280134633.416090583 s in the future
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/byteorder/
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/byteorder/big_endian.h: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:38 is 280134633.415909986 s in the future
rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/byteorder/generic.h
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/byteorder/generic.h: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:38 is 280134633.415770465 s in the future

[...]

rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/rtw_xmit.h
tar: rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116/include/rtw_xmit.h: time stamp 2012-11-16 13:06:38 is 280134633.360691402 s in the future
Please select card type(1/2):
1) RTL8188eus
2) RTL8189es
#? 1
You have selected RTL8188eus
rtw_version.h has existed!
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8188e/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8188e ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build M=/home/vivek/Linux/driver/rtl8188EUS_rtl8189ES_linux_v4.1.2.2_5805.20121116  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
root@debian:/home/vivek/Linux#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, as the message reads you don't have the specified file or directory. Check [this](http://systemadmin.es/2014/06/instalar-los-headers-del-kernel-en-debian) link, it is in Spanish, but the important part is `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, which will install the headers, so that you can compile programs that reference those headers.

Comment: will it work if the machine is not connected to the internet?

Comment: No, you will have to get yourself an ethernet connection.

Comment: Denpends on where your sources.list point to. If they point to a CD and you have the requested package and its dependencies in that CD you won't need internet.

Comment: Or, if that fails, you can follow the instructions in this link, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27100/how-to-install-kernel-on-debian-with-no-internet-connection

Comment: points to my intsall DVD have the first three DVD that come with Debian Wheezy i hope it will be included in the Source list.

Comment: Then you should be OK, try the command and if it doesn't work with the first one try the other DVDs.

Comment: Thanks the script compiled after i did what you suggested @YoMismo

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this is supported by the testing/unstable
`firmware-realtek` package.

The following are listed in the contents.

```
* Realtek RTL8188EE firmware (rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin)
* Realtek RTL8188EU firmware (rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin)
```

Why not try that?